# Adding a subview above the status bar iOS 7

Tags: ios, view, statusbar, addsubview

Ive got a small rectangular view that animates down from the top of my app. I need it to be at the very top of the screen and animate down over the status bar, however the animated view is appearing under the status bar. Anyone know how I can get it over the status bar??

here is what Im doing currently

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.headerView];
```

It works perfectly and is in the correct position EXCEPT for the fact its underneath the status bar. Any ideas?

edit: I know this is possible because snapchat does it.

Comment: You can't put anything over the status bar.  Best you can do is turn it off while the view is on screen, then back on when you remove the subview.

Comment: @nhgrif how can I dynamically turn it off and then on again? Ive looked at posts that mention adding something to the plist file, but I only need it off for 5 seconds on a specific view controller, not the entirety of my app

Comment: One of the `plist` options, I believe, allows individual view controllers to turn it off or on themselves.

Answer (score 1):

One option you can do is, when you animating the headerView of yours,

1. take snapshot of the statusbar
2. hide statusbar
3. add subview of snapshot view on the statusbar position
4. do the header view animation over snapshot view
5. remove snapshot view and show statusbar again.

This way you can get nice animation which looks like it's doing over status bar.

Edit: I will try to explain in pseudo-code

```
// 1. take snapshot of the status bar
UIView* snapshotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];

// 2. hide statusbar
_statusBarHidden = YES;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

// you need to set "View controller-based status bar appearance" option to yes on plist
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return _statusBarHidden;
}

// 3. add subview of snapshot view on the statusbar position
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.height = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
[self.view addSubView:snapshotView];

// 4. do the header view animation over snapshot view
.. Just do the animation you already were doing

// 5. remove snapshot view and show statusbar again.
[snapshotView removeFromSuperview];

_statusBarHidden = NO;
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Comment: how do I take a snapshot of the bar?